# How do you make words type out from a list? ex. instructables.com

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create something similar to "Let Make"**_** where words are typed out from a list on http://www.instructables.com/.

Tried searching here or google for "random word list" and similar terms but not getting anywhere.

Would appreciate any guidance on what what language or function is used to create that.

Comment: Have a look at the setInterval() function. It calls a function every x seconds. All you have to do is make your function take the current value of a textbox and add a letter to the end. The setInterval() function will take care of the timer.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What specific issue are you having? Based on your javascript and html5 tags it looks like you already have at least some idea of what languages you could use.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Beginner here. Trying to get a idea how to accomplish this. Javascript is an educated guess. What function is used to create this so I can look it up. Thx! JohnP suggested setInterval() to make the words appear. What do I use to draw the words from the list and how to make them appear that they are typed out. Advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this (http://jsfiddle.net/ARsyj/) may also point you in the right direction:

```
var arrWordsList = ["ice cream", "bikes", "jewelry"];
var iCurrentWordIndex = 0;
var iCurrentLetterIndex = 0;
var iIntervalId;

function startPrintWords(iInterval) {
    iIntervalId = setInterval(printWords, iInterval);
}

function stopPrintWords() {
    clearInterval(iIntervalId);
}

function printWords() {
    if(iCurrentWordIndex + 1 > arrWordsList.length) {
        stopPrintWords();
        return;
    }

    var strCurrentText = $("#textbox").val();
    var strCurrentWord = arrWordsList[iCurrentWordIndex];

    $("#textbox").val(strCurrentText 
                      + strCurrentWord.charAt(iCurrentLetterIndex));

    if(strCurrentWord.length == iCurrentLetterIndex) {
        iCurrentLetterIndex = 0;
        iCurrentWordIndex++;
        $("#textbox").val("");
    } else {
        iCurrentLetterIndex++;
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
   startPrintWords(1000); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can start with something like this  - http://jsfiddle.net/HhTVd/

```
var word   = ['i', ' l', 'i', 'k', 'e ',  'c', 'a', 'k', 'e'].reverse();
var intervalTimer = setInterval(function(){
    if (word.length == 0) {
        clearInterval(intervalTimer);//clear the timer wehn we have no letters
        return;
    }

    $('#txt').val($('#txt').val() + word.pop())
}, 300)
```

Comment: Thx JohnP! You have saved me countless of hours and hair.

Comment: If you change `word.pop()` to `word.shift()`, then you can lose the `.reverse()`.

Comment: Thanks Rocket Hazmat for introducing 2 more functions to study. That worked too, but is there any benefit in doing that?

Comment: RocketHazmat is absolutely right. @unogeo the advantage is you have one less method to call. Always a good thing. Also, cake!